# Where can I find all mongodb keywords?

Tags: mongodb

I am creating a MongoDB editor and want to highlight all the MongoDB keywords like: `db`, `show`, `dbs`, `use`, etc. Where can I find the list of keywords used in MongoDB?

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the commands and methods from [Database Commands](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/) and [mongo Shell Methods](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/) .

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the commands are shown in `help`. Some of the commands are shown [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/mongo-shell/).

`edit` isn't in this list for example